# Is there a way to locate dropped items?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I'm playing Skyrim on the PS3,
I stole these rings from the Arcaneum: 
Katarina's Ring 
Treoy's Ring 
Balwen's Ring 
Pithiken's Ring

I thought they weren't good for anything so I dropped them god knows where, later on I found this journal under winterhold collage saying that I have to put the rings on the Deadric Relic (hand).
So any idea how I can locate my rings?
I cant load the game I'm way too far ahead of when I dropped them.
and PS3 have no console , correct me if I'm wrong
I don't remember where I dropped them , I might also possibly sold them would they still be at the vendor to buy them back if so?

Please help , I'd really appreciate if I can find how do I get the rings back

Comment: On the PC version, you can retrieve them (or get copies) using player.additem on the console.  Sorry this isn't much help, but under certain circumstances you may be able to transfer your save file to a friend's PC and fix it there. See http://www.maxconsole.com/maxcon_forums/showthread.php?187848-TESV-Skyrim-PS3-Save-Files-decrypted-allowing-conversion-between-platforms!.

Answer (score 5):

I dont think you are going to be able to find them or get them back without back tracking every step you have taken so far.  I know this isnt what you wanted to hear.  I would try to remember at least the kind of area you might have dropped them in.  Like if you think it is a cave like area then go to all the caves you have been to.

While your doing this you could gather all the loot you left your first time in so that your not really wasting your time.  You could make a ton of gold and find your rings.

If you sold these to a merchant then I believe you are SOL.  Venders inventory resets after a while and by the way it sounds a lot of time has went by in your game since you have had the rings.  Good luck on finding your lost treasures.

Comment: yeah a lot of time passed :(
I think I'll just let them go :/ I'm lvl 33 it would take me forever to go in every cave
Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: Haha I did exactly the same except I'm level 62 I put them near a tree so I would remember where they were, turns out I don't remember stuff as good as I thought, it's somewhere in the reach, time to get looking

Answer (score 2):

I was dumb enough to drop chillrend god knows where in the wilderness, I ended up locating it by going back to the last save when I had it in my inventory, then remembering where I went and what quests I did shortly after, so you can try that.

Answer (score 0):

You need to start over. There's no way to get them back.